# Importing HANA tables to R

Tags: r, hana

Is there any known way or package to pull data out of SAP HANA into R dataframe whether through API or some other connector?

Comment: You might want to look at https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/09/machine-learning-with-sap-hana-from-r/ and https://lbreddemann.org/tag/hana-ml-r/

Comment: @Henry I appreciate the response. That's they info I was looking for

Comment: If you manage to get something to work, it might be kind to others to answer your own question with a summary of what you did, and then accept your answer

Comment: @Henry - Absolutely... Thanks for the comment